Quadrupole radiation formula for gravity
I derived the formula for the quadrupole radiation power emitted by a system of masses:
$$P=\frac{1}{45}\dddot{Q}_{kl}\dddot{Q}_{kl} .\quad\quad (*)$$
Note here that: (1) I am using geometrized units, so $c=G=1$; (2) $Q$ is the quadrupole tensor
$$Q_{kl} = \int{(3x_k x_l - δ_{kl}\cdot r^2 )ρ} \, dV \quad (r^2\equiv x_k x_k)$$
and (3) repeated indices are summed over. (In Euclidean space $R^3$, all indices are subscripts.)
This is essentially the same formula given by Landau & Lifshitz "Classical Theory of Fields, 4th Ed." (Eq. (110.16), p. 355) and Ohanian & Ruffini "Gravitation and Spacetime" (Eq. (5.75), p. 195):
$$P=\frac{G}{45c^5}\dddot{Q}_{kl}\dddot{Q}_{kl} .$$
Landau & Lifshitz keep all factors of $c$ and $G$, while Ohanian uses $c=1$ but keeps $G$ separate.
What I want to do is simply convert from geometrized units to conventional units, which means $t$ should be replaced by $ct$ and mass $m$ (or mass density $\rho$) should be replaced by $Gm/c^2$ (or $G\rho/c^2$).
Where I'm having trouble is that the power formula has a product $\dddot{Q}_{kl}\dddot{Q}_{kl}$. So it seems to me that the correct way to convert $(*)$ to conventional units would be
$$P=\frac{1}{45} \left( \frac{G}{c^5} \right)^2 \dddot{Q}_{kl}\dddot{Q}_{kl} .$$
Obviously this is wrong -- only one factor of $G/c^5$ should be used, which is also consistent with dimensional analysis. (In geometrized units, both sides of $(*)$ are dimensionless.)
I'm just not seeing why I should only add one factor of $G/c^5$, when surely each factor of $\dddot{Q}_{kl}$ carries its own factor of $G/c^5$? What am I missing here?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_in_general_relativity#Gravitational_radiation
has formulae with all the G and c factors, with citations to Landau & Lifshitz and journal articles.

Thanks for the comment but this does not help. There are derivations in L&L and O&R using different systems of units. My question really boils down to what I am overlooking in a simple conversion of a (correct) formula from geometrized to conventional units.

$P$ has dimensions of $[\rm mass][length]^2/[time]^3$. So it  will also “eat” a power of $G/c^5$.
To clarify this lets introduce an overhat notation for the dimensional geometrization of an object. In this notation OP's (*) equation is
$$\hat{P}=\frac{1}{45}\widehat{\dddot{Q}}_{kl}\widehat{\dddot{Q}}_{kl}.$$
As the OP correctly deduced
$$ \widehat{\dddot{Q}}_{kl} = \frac{G}{c^5} \dddot{Q}_{kl}.$$
What they were missing was that we also have that
$$\hat{P} =  \frac{G}{c^5} P.$$
Consequently, (*) becomes
$$\frac{G}{c^5}P=\frac{1}{45}\left( \frac{G}{c^5}\right)^2{\dddot{Q}}_{kl}{\dddot{Q}}_{kl},$$
which reduces to
$$P=\frac{1}{45} \frac{G}{c^5}{\dddot{Q}}_{kl}{\dddot{Q}}_{kl} .$$
Reproducing the formula from Landua and Lifshitz.

Yes, I know that by dimensional analysis, only one factor of $Gc^{-5}$ is correct. But I am not seeing why I should ignore the product of two factors of $\dddot{Q}$. What do you mean by "eat"?

@KhunChang There is also a factor of $G/c^5$ that appears on the left hand side of the equation (because of the dimensions of P). This factor will cancel one of the factors on the right hand side.

Aha! Got it ... thank you!
